# Get the same exact syntax of Javascript engine (and code) representation of Arrays

Tags: javascript

I guess I need something like `Array.toString()` but it alters a little how we represent an Array in code.

```
var fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];
fruits.toString();
```

It returns `"Banana,Orange,Apple,Mango"` which is different from`["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"]`,

My purpose is to inject it to some *JS-SQL* driver statement. I hope this is clear.

Comment: *"My purpose is to inject it to some JS-SQL driver statement."* **Don't**. Instead, use whatever mechanism that API provides for parameterized statements. (I couldn't find a project that matched "JS-SQL" specifically, to check.)

Comment: I know what are you referring to T.J. It it is a private solution, and there is no mechanism to do so. No String can be injected other than values generated at run-time and values are sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For that you can just `stringify` it via [`JSON.stringify()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) and get the array's representation as *JSON*.

```js
let fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];
let str = JSON.stringify(fruits);

console.log(str);
```